# Managing payments outside the app store

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store

We are in the process of developing a Cordova iPhone/iPad application, our plan is to release the app in the store as a free app.

We initially thought we would be able to offer full and free use of the app for 30 days, after which we would ask the user to pay to access the app.

The payment would be managed outside of the app (i.e. Not an in-app purchase), circumventing Apple's mechanism and the revenue split.

However from all the reading we've done around in-app subscriptions and taking payment outside of the app store it appears this may not be possible and we will struggle to get the app approved.

In an ideal world we would:

1. Publish the app
2. User download the app
3. User uses the app for 30 days
4. On day 31 we ask the user to pay for continued access
5. User taps a button and pays via our payment gateway
6. User returns to the app and can continue to use the app forever

We will also be releasing a web app, same functionality and same payment process required.

Im almost 100% sure that Apple will turn us down for this, we are essentially offering a trial of the app and then asking for payment simply to circumvent the revenue split - at least thats how it can be interpreted.

I'm trying to find a workflow (user journey) that would work in our case but also with the app store process.

Thinking something potentially like the Spotify model, where a subscription is required (Username/Password) and then the app is downloaded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your original idea is going to get you rejected for sure. What's wrong with offering some of the features through IAP?

From the submission guidelines:

> 2.9 Apps that are "beta", "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected
>
> 11.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
>
> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected

Additionally, you can do the subscription model, but beware of this as well:

> 11.12 Apps offering subscriptions must do so using IAP, Apple will share the same 70/30 revenue split with developers for these purchases, as set forth in the Program License Agreement
>
> 11.13 Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a "buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected
>
> 11.14 Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video and cloud storage) that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the App, as long as there is no button or external link in the App to purchase the approved content. Apple will only receive a portion of revenues for content purchased inside the App

Comment: Your best bet on that is definitely the subscription model then. Just make sure you don't have any type of purchase button anywhere in your app. Also think what sort of experience your users will get if they don't have a paid subscription. Without the ability to tell them they need to sign up, are they going to know to go to your site? Is the app going to be completely unusable for the unsubscribed?

Comment: Really useful comments, certainly presents some issues with the user journey. The app does require login for access, but with no way to communicate the need for payment after 30 days our comm's need to be spot on.

Comment: How does Spotify get around this then?

Comment: Spotify offers their subscriptions as IAP. They also offer subscriptions on their site that aren't subject to Apple's cut. They don't link out to those options directly and all subscription purchases made in app are accomplished through IAP. You can use accept payment for subscriptions outside your app, you just can't link to those options from your app. Also, a lot has changed in the last 4 and a half years, my original post might not be completely accurate at this point. I would take a look through the submission guidelines directly.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like Apple become less strict to that rule. I can't find any mentions like this: "Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected" in current docs.

Here is a new one:

> 3.1.1 In-App Purchase: If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game
>   currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a
>   full version), you must use in-app purchase.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase

Also, Netflix has launched the app with the ability to buy a subscription outside of the Appstore:

https://www.extremetech.com/mobile/276066-netflix-experiments-with-bypassing-apple-app-store-subscription-fees

Comment: Netflix and Spotify are being treated as exception. We, simple mortals don't have such privilege.

Comment: @ÉderRocha we are now in the same situation, but ALL of our competitors (small local companies) somehow managed to make their apps to pass the review step and offer a button that simply opens a webpage outside of the app with a web payment system. Still cannot figure how they did it. Makes me hate Apple strategies even more.